# execute perl in command line without specifying perl in UNIX

Tags: perl, bash, unix, command-line

There is a similar question about Windows, but it won't work for Unix based computers (OS X specifically).

I want to type the name of a file, say `example.pl` or `example.pl parametertext.txt`, and have it know to execute perl.

I specified `#!/usr/bin/perl` in the file so it can find the executable.  Instead, I get the message:

```
bash: example.pl: command not found
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `#!/usr/bin/perl`? With no-spaces (not sure if that matters) and a full path? Also, is your .pl file executable? (try `chmod +x example.pl`). Not to mention if `.` isn't in your `PATH`, then you need to run `./example.pl`, rather than `example.pl`.

Comment: Also did you set the file executable?  What does "not working" mean, can you give the error message(s)?

Comment: @DanFego yes, I think autocorrect bumped it over but I did forget the /

Comment: @EdwardThomson `last | ctime.pl` is what I'm trying to execute
`-bash: ctime.pl: command not found`

Comment: You really shouldn't correct your code in the question to remove the problem. This entry no longer makes any sense!

Comment: @Den Fego  No, it is supposed to be `#!/usr/bin/env perl`

Comment: @Borodin that wasn't the problem, since it was correct in the file. The question of how to run .pl files without typing `perl` still remains, and was answered below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it this way,

1. Find the interpreter/executors path. In this case its `/usr/bin/perl` or `/usr/bin/env perl`
2. Add it to the first line of the file as `#!/usr/bin/perl`.
3. Give execute permission to the file `chmod +x example.pl`

Now it will run

```
    $ ./example.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the top line (the "shebang") `#!/usr/bin/perl` (note the slash where you have a space). Then, first you need to make sure that is actually the correct path to your `perl` executable (type `which perl` to see where it is). If it's elsewhere, correct the path appropriately.  Then you need to make sure the script has the execute permission set. Type `ls -l example.pl`, and look for an `x` in the first column (fourth character, in particular). If it's not there, you need to make the script executable with `chmod a+x example.pl`. Finally, to run the program, you need to use `./example.pl`.  The `./` tells your shell that you want the script in your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have two thoughts to add:

1) To use example.pl test1.txt your path should contain a dot.
echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/bin/X11:.

2) Your file end of line should be unix, \n. At least your shebang line contain excatly your perl path, ended with a \n.